# Windows CE: Sharing memory between OAL and kernel driver

Tags: windows-ce, xilinx

Is there a way to share memory between OAL and kernel driver? Between OAL and kernel there is NKGlobal structure which can be used to share memory. I would like a similar approach to share the memory. I am using Windows Embedded Compact 2013 on Xilinx board.

Thus far, in the OAL layer I did VirtToPhys to an allocated memory to get the physical address. In the kernel driver I tried VirtualAllocCopyEx but I dont know what to pass in the pAddr.

```
  LPVOID VirtualAllocCopyEx (
       HANDLE hSrcProc,
       HANDLE hDstProc,
       LPVOID pAddr,
       DWORD cbSize,
       DWORD dwProtect
  );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the driver is running in kernel mode it's sharing the same address space of the OAL, so you can pass pointers directly. You can allocate your buffer in the driver or in the OAL and share a value using an IOCTL implemented in OEMIoControl in your OAL (if your BSP uses the common production quality layer you may check how other IOCTLs are implemented, usually you need to add a record in a table of structs and implement a function to manage your specific IOCTL).
Both components can access the memory using that pointer.

Comment: If in the kernel mode driver I do g_pNKGlobal = (PNKGlobal) 0x8287a087(the address printed from OAL). And then RETAILMSG(1, (L"Version: %08x\r\n", g_pNKGlobal->dwVersion). I get the system error running user code in kernel.

Comment: If you need to share this kind of information implementing a custom kernel IOCTL would be the best option. But you should be able to access that memory location because 0x80000000 is the start address of kernel memory. Are you sure that your driver is running in kernel mode?

Comment: I am 100% sure that it's running in kernel mode. I can access the GPIO registers. I suspect somehow the memory is protected and cant be accessed from the kernel driver. Thats why the OAL and Kernel communicate with each other by using NKGlobal and OEMGlobal structure.

Comment: NKGlobal and OEMGlobal were used in CE 5.0, they have been kept in place to ease migration from CE 5.0 to CE 6.0 where the kernel is a DLL and no longer a static lib linked to the kernel executable.

Comment: AFAIK memory protection in Windows CE is between processes and kernel mode driver are running in the kernel process, there is no context switch when calling kernel functions and so no remap of the MMU. Looking at your address I notice that it's an even number, are you sure about it? Pointer on ARM must be 32bit aligned (unless you use the unaligned keyword to define them) and also on x86 a structure in memory is usually packed at 32 bit.

Comment: Its working now. I dont know why it was giving error. Thanks. Just wondering if I can share the memory from OAL to user mode. I can do it from kernel mode driver to user space.